# Ruby on Rails Automatic Variable Name (Plural vs Singular)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, activerecord, plural

I am building a rails app that has several quizzes with the exact same structure:

- A name such as `@quiz_bf` or `@quiz_bs`
- `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` views for each quiz
- A partial `_quiz.html.erb` that stores the actual quiz questions for each quiz
- A model and controller for each separate quiz
- Two places (the main nav and a user profile page) hold a link to the `new` view (or to the `edit` view if people have already taken the quiz, decided by an erb if/else statement) of each quiz

I successfully managed to set up the first quiz, but as I am new to Ruby I made the (terrible) mistake of setting up a variable name that ended in -s (`quiz_bs`) for the singular version of the quiz.  This wrought havoc with Ruby's singular vs. plural naming conventions.

I currently have the code for my second quiz (`quiz_bf`) set up, but am getting a no method error saying `undefined method 'quiz_bfs' for #<User:0x007fb9a3247f98>` on the definition of new quiz in my controller.

Here's my controller:

```
class QuizBfController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_sign_in

def show
  @quiz_bf = QuizBf.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @quiz_bf = current_user.quiz_bfs || current_user.build_quiz_bfs
end

def create
  @quiz_bf = QuizBf.new

  @quiz_bf.bf01 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf01]
  @quiz_bf.bf02 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf02]
  @quiz_bf.bf03 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf03]
  @quiz_bf.bf04 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf04]
  @quiz_bf.bf05 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf05]
  @quiz_bf.bf06 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf06]
  @quiz_bf.bf07 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf07]
  @quiz_bf.bf08 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf08]
  @quiz_bf.bf09 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf09]
  @quiz_bf.bf10 = params[:quiz_bfs][:bf10]

  @quiz_bf.user = current_user

  if @quiz_bf.save
    flash[:notice] = "Quiz results saved successfully."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your quiz results failed to save."
    redirect_to welcome_index_path
  end
  end

  def edit
    @quiz_bf = QuizBf.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  @quiz_bf = QuizBf.find(params[:id])

  @quiz_bf.assign_attributes(quiz_bfs_params)

  if @quiz_bf.save
    flash[:notice] = "Post was updated successfully."
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
    redirect_to welcome_index_path
    end
    end

    private
    def quiz_bfs_params
    params.require(:quiz_bfs).permit(:bf01, :bf02, :bf03, :bf04, :bf05, :bf06, :bf07, :bf08, :bf09, :bf10)
    end

    end
```

Here's my model (user `has_one :quiz_bf`):

```
class QuizBf < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :set_bfcode

def set_bfcode
  self.bfcode = "#{self.bf01}#{self.bf02}#{self.bf03}-#{self.bf04}#{self.bf05}#{self.bf06}-#{self.bf07}#{self.bf08}#{self.bf09}#{self.bf10}"
end

belongs_to :user
validates :user, presence: true
end
```

Here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

validates :name, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 100 }, presence: true
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, unless: :password_digest
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true
validates :email,
        presence: true,
        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
        length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 254 }

has_secure_password

has_one :quiz_bs
has_one :quiz_bf
```

end

Here are the germane bits of my quiz partial:

```
<%= form_for @quiz_bf do |f| %>

...

<%= f.submit "Submit Answers" %>
```

Here's how I'm linking from my `new` view:

```
<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { url: quiz_bfs_path, method: :post } %>
```

And my `edit` view:

```
<%= render "quiz", url: quiz_bf_path(@quiz_bf), method: :put  %>
```

And (finally) here's how I'm linking to it from my `application` view:

```
          <% if current_user.quiz_bfs == nil? %>
             <%= link_to "Body Flexibility Quiz", quiz_bf_path %>
          <% else %>
             <%= link_to "Body Flexibility Quiz ✓", edit_quiz_bf_path(current_user.quiz_bfs) %>
          <% end %>
```

And my users `show` page:

```
  <% if @user.quiz_bfs == nil %>
    <p><%= link_to "Test Your Body Flexibility", new_quiz_bf_path %></p>
  <% else %>
    <h3><%= @user.quiz_bfs.bfcode %></h3>
    <p><%= link_to "Retest Results", edit_quiz_bf_path(@user.quiz_bfs) %></p>
  <% end %>
```

I know this code worked successfully for the `quiz_bs`, but as you can see in my rake routes (shown below), the plural/singular issue of my idiotic variable name made it hard to see what was actually named what.  Can anyone with more experienced ruby eyes than mine show me what I need to change?

```
        quiz_bs GET    /quiz_bs(.:format)             quiz_bs#index
                POST   /quiz_bs(.:format)             quiz_bs#create
     new_quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/new(.:format)         quiz_bs#new
    edit_quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/:id/edit(.:format)    quiz_bs#edit
         quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#show
                PATCH  /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#update
                PUT    /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#update
                DELETE /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#destroy
  quiz_bf_index GET    /quiz_bf(.:format)             quiz_bf#index
                POST   /quiz_bf(.:format)             quiz_bf#create
    new_quiz_bf GET    /quiz_bf/new(.:format)         quiz_bf#new
   edit_quiz_bf GET    /quiz_bf/:id/edit(.:format)    quiz_bf#edit
        quiz_bf GET    /quiz_bf/:id(.:format)         quiz_bf#show
                PATCH  /quiz_bf/:id(.:format)         quiz_bf#update
                PUT    /quiz_bf/:id(.:format)         quiz_bf#update
                DELETE /quiz_bf/:id(.:format)         quiz_bf#destroy
```

Comment: Can you post your user model?

Comment: There are bigger problems here. You should not have dozens of fields with the same name and a different number like this, all of your `@quiz_bf.bf01` variables should not be set up that way. You should be either storing these as related records, or simply serializing an array so that you can just *loop* over the fields.

Comment: Has your User model got `has_many :quiz_bfs` ?  If not then `@user.quiz_bfs` would be undefined.

Comment: I just added the user model in an edit.  It `has_one :quiz_bf`.

Comment: Why are you using quiz_bfs when your model only sets up quiz_bs and quiz_bf associations?

Comment: @FrederickCheung You are correct.  I removed the quiz_bfs.  The error message changed into a url generation error saying `No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"quiz_bf", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` on this line: `<%= link_to "Body Flexibility Quiz ✓", edit_quiz_bf_path(current_user.quiz_bf) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Undefined method error

The issue with the undefined method probably has to do with the call being a plural call (`quiz_bfs`), which expects that you have a has_many association, while your model only defines a has_one association:

```
has_one :quiz_bs
has_one :quiz_bf
```

Either a) the use of `quiz_bfs` is a typo and should be `quiz_bf`, b) the has_one is incorrect, or c) you don't need the call to `current_user.quiz_bfs` at all to assign a value to `@quiz_bf`.  It's hard to tell without knowing more details, but it looks like you can just remove `current_user.quiz_bfs`.

## Bonus on routes

While it wasn't this question, specifically, you mentioned the pain of a resource ending in 's' being treated as a plural.  If you haven't seen it yet, you can have your `quiz_bs` routes named appropriately.  To do so, you can use this form in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
resources :quiz_bs, as: :quiz_bs
```

This *should* give you the route helper names that you would like.  You can read more about that in the [Overriding Named Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers) section of [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

You may want to name your controller `QuizBsController`, as well, and you can use the `controller:` override on the resources route definition to do that.  Try this and see if it gives you the right controller:

```
resources :quiz_bs, controller: 'quiz_bs'
```

You can always combine both route methods and use something like this:

```
resources :quiz_bs, controller: 'quiz_bs', as: :quiz_bs
```

Check out the [Specifying a Controller to Use](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use) section of [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information and usage details.